# Best way to interact between Application bar and Conductor using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've been trying to use the application bar(with caliburn `AppBarButton` items of course) which is expected to change its set of buttons and their actions depending on active pivot item.

The items are represented via Screen viewmodels and their parent is `Conductor` whose view contains the app bar.

I'm really stuck with the above and basically I can't figure out two things:

1) How do I correctly access Application bar and bind its button messages right from my viewmodel when `LoadedPivotItem` is triggered? When I add some buttons specifying their Message properties like `Message = "DoSomething"` there, nothing happens on click. When I do this in XAML, everything is fine. `OnInitialize` or .ctor also work fine but I actually need to know what pivot item was selected to inject correct buttons!

2) When button action triggers, how do I pass it correctly to child Screen so it will call its own method? Is event aggregator the only correct way to do this?

Please give me some code examples if possible - I couldn't find anything on the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem by myself.

Basically I've tried several third-party application bars and discarded all of them. Though one may look into them if interested:

- http://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/
- http://shwp.codeplex.com/

None of them worked for me, however only due to caliburn in my project. In normal situations they would fit perfectly since the first one allows defining ButtonsSource and the second one allows set custom buttons for each pivot/panorama item right in XAML! Wow!

I used this link: http://www.markermetro.com/2010/07/technical/windows-phone-7-creating-that-elusive-reusable-application-bar/ which answered my question number one.

As for the second question I currently just perform a check whether child viewmodel is active and then call its appropriate method from the `Conductor`. A bit dirty I know, but at this point still better than nothing.